# Why my suggested edit was rejected?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, specific-edit

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6482783/447356) there is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13264524/447356) that suggests starting an activity for the market, and fall back to popping up a toast if the market app can't be found.

I [suggested an improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2183266) (clicked the edit link) that would fall back to the browser if the market app couldn't be found, which works quite nicely for me, but several people rejected that edit however, with the reason:

> This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post

I'm not quite sure why that would be rejected. Is the code wrong? Or am I using Stack Overflow wrongly?

Edit: I was not given an option to comment on the solution (I'm not sure why) otherwise that would have been an obvious thing to do.

Comment: You're using stack overflow wrongly.  If you're suggesting an improvement to an approach, you should comment on the answer rather than edit the original-  editing is more for formatting mistakes, typos, minor but obvious coding errors.  Actually this question is in the wrong place itself, it belongs on meta.stackexchange.com.  Btw, I think the idea in your edit is a nice improvement, it just should have been made separate as a comment.

Comment: Thanks for that - just after I created this post I actually realised the problem in my code, the original question specified: _Considering they could acquire it from Amazon.com or Google Marketplace..._ I realised that my "improvement" wouldn't at all satisfy that need!

Also: I wasn't able to comment on the original post, but I could suggest changes.

Comment: Please do not suggest any more changes until you've read and understood how SO/SE works.

Comment: I do apologise, but this is an attempt to understand how SO/SE works. I did read the instructions for suggesting edits carefully and at the trime it felt like commenting was more appropriate. However for some reason I was unable to comment so I assumed that suggesting edits was the correct thing to do. I'm not sure I should be criticised for following what the UI and documentation were leading me to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My 'edit' should have been made as a comment to the original answer, however I didn't have enough reputation to add a comment (50 rep required).

The only recourse in situations like this is to add a new answer to the question.